# Find Reference To Resource String In Windows 3.1 16-bit DLL with IDA Pro

Tags: ida, windows, assembly, x86

Experimenting Visual Basic 4 in DosBox + Windows 3.1 running on Windows 10. While I have installed SHARE.exe from MS-DOS 6.22 and it seems to run OK, it still fails to detect it.

The error I get is : "SHARE.exe must be installed in order to run Visual Basic"

I wanted to work out how the SHARE.exe detection works. I installed the Windows 3.1 SDK and tried to debug with CodeView. However I can't figure out how to set a breakpoint on MESSAGEBOX, and I can't use the keyboard shortcut to "halt" the system and break into CodeView as it seems to be passed to Windows host instead of Dosbox.

An analysis of VBIDE.dll I can find the error message:

```
res098:0000 ; Resource, type (8006): String table
res098:0000 ; File offset      : 26CB0h  Length: 0100h
res098:0000 ; Attributes (1C30): Movable Pure
res098:0000 ; Resource ID      : 3143
res098:0000 ; ===========================================================================
res098:0000
res098:0000 ; Segment type: Regular
res098:0000 res098          segment para public 'RESOURCE' use16
res098:0000                 assume cs:res098
res098:0000                 assume es:nothing, ss:nothing, ds:nothing, fs:nothing, gs:nothing
res098:0000 a8shareExeMustB db '8SHARE.EXE must be installed in order to run Visual Basic',0
res098:003A aRecordsourcePr db '>RecordSource property of the associated data control is empty.MV'
res098:003A                 db 'isual Basic was not able to start up due to an invalid system con'
```

The VBIDE.dll is referenced in VB.exe this way:

```
cseg15:2EBF                 mov     es, [bp+var_4+2]
cseg15:2EC2                 mov     byte ptr es:[si+1], 0
cseg15:2EC7                 lea     ax, [bp+var_17A]
cseg15:2ECB                 push    ss
cseg15:2ECC                 push    ax              ; LPCSTR
cseg15:2ECD                 push    ds
cseg15:2ECE                 push    offset aVbideDll ; "VBIDE.DLL"
cseg15:2ED1                 call    sub_37E70
cseg15:2ED6                 mov     word_10C9DC, ax
cseg15:2ED9                 or      ax, ax
cseg15:2EDB                 jnz     short loc_389CC
cseg15:2EDD                 push    ds
cseg15:2EDE                 push    offset aVbideDll_0 ; "VBIDE.DLL"
cseg15:2EE1                 push    ds
cseg15:2EE2                 push    offset aTheLanguageDll ; "The language DLL '%s' could not be foun"...
cseg15:2EE5                 lea     ax, [bp+var_27A]
```

I suspect this word_10C9DC location is important, and it's referenced when calling LOADSTRING (Some examples there are many more)

```
cseg09:269A                 enter   50h, 0
cseg09:269E                 push    word_10C9DC     ; HINSTANCE
cseg09:26A2                 push    7D0h            ; UINT
cseg09:26A5                 lea     ax, [bp+var_28]
cseg09:26A8                 push    ss
cseg09:26A9                 push    ax              ; LPSTR
cseg09:26AA                 push    28h ; '('       ; int
cseg09:26AC                 call    LOADSTRING
cseg09:26B1                 push    word_10C9DC     ; HINSTANCE
cseg09:26B5                 push    [bp+arg_2]      ; UINT
cseg09:26B8                 lea     ax, [bp+var_50]
cseg09:26BB                 push    ss
cseg09:26BC                 push    ax              ; LPSTR
cseg09:26BD                 push    28h ; '('       ; int
cseg09:26BF                 call    LOADSTRING
cseg09:26C4                 lea     ax, [bp+var_28]
cseg09:26C7                 push    ss
cseg09:26C8                 push    ax              ; LPCSTR
cseg09:26C9                 lea     ax, [bp+var_50]
cseg09:26CC                 push    ss
cseg09:26CD                 push    ax              ; LPCSTR
cseg09:26CE                 push    [bp+arg_0]      ; int
cseg09:26D1                 push    seg cseg04
cseg09:26D4                 push    offset aVbIni   ; "VB.INI"
cseg09:26D7                 call    GETPRIVATEPROFILEINT
cseg09:26DC                 leave
```

There is a few MESSAGEBOX references:

MessageBox #1

```
cseg05:0EC8                 push    0               ; HWND
cseg05:0ECA                 les     bx, dword_10C1F8
cseg05:0ECE                 add     bx, es:[bx+9Ah]
cseg05:0ED3                 push    es
cseg05:0ED4                 push    bx              ; LPCSTR
cseg05:0ED5                 push    0
cseg05:0ED7                 push    0               ; LPCSTR
cseg05:0ED9                 push    10h             ; UINT
cseg05:0EDB                 call    MESSAGEBOX
```

MessageBox #2

```
cseg15:2FE2                 push    0               ; HWND
cseg15:2FE4                 les     bx, dword_10C1F8
cseg15:2FE8                 add     bx, es:[bx+9Eh]
cseg15:2FED                 push    es
cseg15:2FEE                 push    bx              ; LPCSTR
cseg15:2FEF                 push    seg cseg02
cseg15:2FF2                 push    offset byte_9EC8 ; LPCSTR
cseg15:2FF5                 push    1010h           ; UINT
cseg15:2FF8                 call    MESSAGEBOX
```

MessageBox #4 & 5

```
cseg47:297E                 push    bp
cseg47:297F                 mov     bp, sp
cseg47:2981                 push    di
cseg47:2982                 push    si
cseg47:2983                 mov     di, [bp+6]
cseg47:2986                 mov     es, word ptr [bp+8]
cseg47:2989                 push    word ptr es:[di]
cseg47:298C                 push    word ptr es:[di+4]
cseg47:2990                 push    word ptr es:[di+2]
cseg47:2994                 push    word ptr es:[di+8]
cseg47:2998                 push    word ptr es:[di+6]
cseg47:299C                 push    word ptr es:[di+0Ah]
cseg47:29A0                 call    MESSAGEBOX
cseg47:29A5                 mov     si, ax
cseg47:29A7                 or      si, ax
cseg47:29A9                 jnz     short loc_B517F
cseg47:29AB                 mov     es, word ptr [bp+8]
cseg47:29AE                 and     word ptr es:[di+0Ah], 0CF0Fh
cseg47:29B4                 push    word ptr es:[di]
cseg47:29B7                 push    word ptr es:[di+4]
cseg47:29BB                 push    word ptr es:[di+2]
cseg47:29BF                 push    word ptr es:[di+8]
cseg47:29C3                 push    word ptr es:[di+6]
cseg47:29C7                 or      word ptr es:[di+0Ah], 1010h
cseg47:29CD                 push    word ptr es:[di+0Ah]
cseg47:29D1                 call    MESSAGEBOX
```

I couldn't work out which messagebox was displaying the message, so I replaced them all with int 3, this allowed me to break into the CodeView debugger. From this I worked out relevant MESSAGEBOX code displaying error was:

```
cseg47:297E                 push    bp
cseg47:297F                 mov     bp, sp
cseg47:2981                 push    di
cseg47:2982                 push    si
cseg47:2983                 mov     di, [bp+6]
cseg47:2986                 mov     es, word ptr [bp+8]
cseg47:2989                 push    word ptr es:[di]
cseg47:298C                 push    word ptr es:[di+4]
cseg47:2990                 push    word ptr es:[di+2]
cseg47:2994                 push    word ptr es:[di+8]
cseg47:2998                 push    word ptr es:[di+6]
cseg47:299C                 push    word ptr es:[di+0Ah]
cseg47:29A0                 call    MESSAGEBOX
```

However there was no xref to this section of code, the only reference I could find to this location was these push statements:

```
loc_B51AB:
mov     ax, [bp+arg_6]
mov     dx, [bp+arg_8]
mov     [bp+var_A], ax
mov     [bp+var_8], dx
mov     ax, [bp+arg_2]
mov     dx, [bp+arg_4]
mov     [bp+var_6], ax
mov     [bp+var_4], dx
mov     ax, [bp+arg_0]
mov     [bp+var_2], ax
push    seg cseg47
push    297Eh
lea     ax, [bp+var_C]
push    ss
push    ax
push    ss
push    ax
call    sub_B4F7C
leave
retf    0Ch
sub_B5188 endp
```

What code set up the message box string here, and is there a way by knowing the details in resource DLL what assembly I should look for when then string is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

From the code you posted, it seems that `sub_B4F7C` is a **function registering handlers**, in this case, function at `297Eh`. This address (function pointer) is probably being saved somewhere by `sub_B4F7C` and will be called when `SHARE.EXE` is not detected.

Thus, this handler won't be called directly; when the event occurs, the code will just check at relevant address for a function registered for that event and call it. It will use the address previously put into memory by `sub_B4F7C`, instead of hardcoded value.

**In short:** don't worry, this function will be called. You can verify it by putting a breakpoint at its beginning. It is also worth to mark this handler as a function (select the relevant fragment and press `P`). You can then right click at `297Eh`, select `offset` and select the offset of the newly created function to display.

**Note:** According to [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ms647486) (for `32`bit, but signature seems to be the same), `word_10C9DC` is the identifier of module containing the strings to load.